# POSIX fdopen() function in C

Tags: c, linux, posix

When should we use fdopen and how do we use it? My understanding of that is when we can't use fopen to read (read from pipe). I don't really understand the description of fdopen on the man page: `The fdopen() function associates a stream with the existing file descriptor, fd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) when you have a file descriptor (`int fd;`) of some sort but you need to call functions that require a file stream (`FILE *fp;`) instead.  This could be a pipe file descriptor, or a socket file descriptor, or any other file descriptor type.

Once you've used `fdopen()`, you *should* not use the file descriptor again — you should use only the file stream.  If you must use a file descriptor as well, it would be best to use `fileno(fp)` rather than the saved `fd`.  Most importantly, if you mix access, you need to ensure that you've flushed the file stream before you do anything with the file descriptor.  (There's no buffering with the file descriptor, so there's less of a problem reverting to the file stream from the file descriptor.). Operations that change the current file position on the file descriptor could mess up the file stream and vice versa (when there is a current position associated with the file descriptor or file stream).  Note that both read and write operations change the current file position — there's not a lot you can do without risking a mess.

You must use `fclose(fp);` to close the file stream (and implicitly the file descriptor).  Do NOT use just `close(fd)` or `close(fileno(fp))`.

Note that POSIX defines [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html) to do formatted output to a file descriptor.  Also, you could use `snprintf()` or its relatives to format data into a string and then write the string to the file descriptor.  This might make it less important to use `fdopen()`.